# Magento 2.4.6 Sample data problem - just 46 products in Gear category

Tags: installation, sample-data

Installed several time for 246 and 245 also. The M2 installation and DB was cleared before every time. Just 46 products in Gear and all. I'm no newbee in this and googled also. Generally it's too simple situation and I wondered, everything was cleared, reindexed, composer version swapped, I tried to find the problems by myself but no idea

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Because you have installed them before but may have failed that time, so the sample data patches have been saved into the **patch_list** table. Therefore, the solution is to delete these sample data patches and then run **setup:upgrade**. However, to avoid any other mistakes, you should delete the database and run **setup:install**.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I need, I removed patches, run upgrade, but got Unable to apply patch Magento\InventoryCatalog\Setup\Patch\Schema\CreateLegacyStockStatusView for module Magento_InventoryCatalog. Original exception message: SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'inventory_stock_1' already exists

Comment: The way to setup:install with ----cleanup-database works well, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an expected behavior. For example, if you open 'Women' or 'Men' category, probably you will see products assigned in the sub-categories.

This happens because 'Men' and 'Women' categories have 'Is Anchor' = 'No'. Meaning that actually no products assigned to this categories. If you set 'Is Anchor' = 'Yes', then you will see the number of products of child categories.

[image]

Magento anchored category contains products assigned to it and all subcategories. A non-anchored Magento category contains only products directly related to it.

Comment: No, the categories below are zero size too [img]https://i.imgur.com/keWA144.png[/img]